# Добавить точку в polyline

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, polyline

Не могу разобраться как добавить точку в уже существующую polyline

```
function setPolyline(car) {
    var options = {
        //---- Задаем опции геообъекта.
        //---- Цвет с прозрачностью.
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        //---- Ширину линии.
        strokeWidth: 4,
        //---- Максимально допустимое количество вершин в ломаной.
        editorMaxPoints: 5000,
        // Первой цифрой задаем длину штриха. Второй цифрой задаем длину разрыва.
        // strokeStyle: '1 5',
        //---- Добавляем в контекстное меню новый пункт, позволяющий удалить ломаную.
        editorMenuManager: function (items) {
            items.push({
                title: "Удалить линию",
                onClick: function () {
                    myMap.geoObjects.remove(myPolyline);
                }
            });
            return items;
        }};

    if ( _storagePolyline[car.car_id] == null ) {
        //---- Хранилище координат
        _storagePolylineCoordinates[car.car_id] = [[car.lat, car.lng]];
        //---- Указываем координаты вершин.
        var myPolyline = new ymaps.Polyline(_storagePolylineCoordinates[car.car_id], {
            hintContent: "Ломаная линия"
        }, options);

        //---- Хранилище линий
        _storagePolyline[car.car_id] = myPolyline;

        //---- Добавляем линию на карту.
        myMap.geoObjects.add(myPolyline);

        //---- Включаем режим редактирования.
        myPolyline.editor.startEditing();
        //---- Включаем режим рисования.
        // myPolyline.editor.startDrawing();
    } else {
        ok = false;
        var len = _storagePolylineCoordinates[car.car_id].length - 1;
        if (_storagePolylineCoordinates[car.car_id][len][0] == car.lat &&
            _storagePolylineCoordinates[car.car_id][len][1] == car.lng ){
            ok = true;
            // console.log(ok);
        }

        if (!ok) {
            console.log(_storagePolyline[car.car_id].geometry);
            _storagePolylineCoordinates[car.car_id].push([car.lat, car.lng]);
            _storagePolyline[car.car_id].setCoordinates(_storagePolylineCoordinates[car.car_id])
            // storagePolyline[car.car_id] = new ymaps.Polyline(storagePolylineCoordinates[car.car_id],{}, options);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте метод геометрии `setCoordinates()`.

[Вот документация.](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geometry.LineString-docpage/?from=SO#methods-summary)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/235166)

Comment: ссылка ровно на метод setCoordinates(), который уже указан в ответе. Спасибо за бдительность!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста, но более развернутый ответ не помешал бы...  Люди должны к нам идти, а не от нас....

Answer (score 0):

Наиболее правильный путь использовать `geometry.insert(index, coordinates)` для добавления и `geometry.remove(index)` для удаления

```
// Наши исходные координаты линии
const coords = [
    [55.1, 61.3],
    [55.2, 61.2]
]

// Создаем линию
const line = new ymaps.Polyline(coords, {}, {
    strokeColor: '#3e9eff',
    strokeWidth: 4,
})

// Добавляем линию на карту
map.geoObjects.add(line)

// Добавляем точку в конец линии
line.geometry.insert(line.geometry.getLength(), [55.3, 61.2])

// Добавляем точку в начало линии
line.geometry.insert(0, [55.0, 61.2])

// Удаляем вторую точку из линии
line.geometry.remove(1)
```